# What is difference between "function" and "function!" in VIM?

Tags: vim, function

I beheld quite a few usage of "function!" in others vimrc files, but there is no easy-to-find documentation of "function!".

What's the difference between "function" and "function!"?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`:help user-functions`

When a function by this name already exists and [!] is
not used an error message is given.  When [!] is used,
an existing function is silently replaced.  Unless it
is currently being executed, that is an error.

Answer (score 9):

In general, it suppresses the messages the command may spit out.

For instance, using `function!`, you can redeclare an already defined function.

Answer (score 6):

`function` (with appropriate) parameters defines a new function but fails if a function already exists with the given name. `function!` will always replace any existing function of the given name with the new definition supplied.

This says as much:

```
:help function
```