# Vim error: cannot create diffs. Vim folder has no diff.exe

Tags: vim, windows-7, diff, vimdiff

When trying to use vim diff to compare two files on windows 7, I get an error message: `cannot create diff`. My vim version is `7.4.965`.

Searching for this on the internet, it seems that `C:/Program Files/Vim/vim74` should normally contain a `diff.exe`: it doesn't in my case.

Is this a correct assumption, and if so, how can I fix my Vim installation?

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23664167/519360), which redefines the diff function.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see vim.exe in this directory?

My vim is installed in `C:/Program Files(x86)/Vim/vim74`