# vimdiff E97 in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, vim, windows-10, vimdiff

I am having trouble getting `vimdiff` to work on a Windows 10 machine. I am running  vim from Powershell. Powershell is also declared in `$myvimrc` as my shell of choice:

```
set shell=C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

The documents I am attempting to compare are not saved as files. I open two vertical splits, enter text into each, and run `:windo diffthis`. The output is `E97: Cannot create diffs`.

[This article](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Running_diff) says I may need to download and use a different `diff.exe` than the one installed with gvim. I have downloaded the recommended "GnuWin32 diff" package and added the install directory to my Windows Path (`$env:path`). Continuing to follow these directions, I've commented out the default `diffexpr` declaration, but still get E97.

I have also tried calling my own function to no avail. In this attempt, I've made sure to escape backslashes, and have also copied the downloaded `diff.exe` to a directory I am confident I have full permissions to. To help with troubleshooting, I've temporarily saved the two files I wish to compare, and specified their full paths explicitly rather than using vim's `v:fname_in` and `v:fname_new` (and `v:fname_out`).

```
set diffexpr=TestDiff()
function TestDiff()
       silent execute "!& " . "C:\\diff.exe" . " -a --binary " "C:\\a.edi" . " " . "C:\\b.edi" . " > " . "C:\\tmp.txt"
endfunction
```

I've researched this error by running `:h E97`, which returns the following information:

> Vim will do a test if the diff output looks alright.  If it doesn't,
>   you will get an error message.  Possible causes:
>
> - The "diff" program cannot be executed.
> - The "diff" program doesn't produce normal "ed" style diffs (see above).
> - The 'shell' and associated options are not set correctly.  Try if filtering    works with a command like ":!sort".
> - You are using 'diffexpr' and it doesn't work. If it's not clear what the problem is set the 'verbose' option to one or more to see
>     more messages.
>
> The self-installing Vim for MS-Windows includes a diff program.  If
>   you don't have it you might want to download a diff.exe.  For example
>   from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm.

I believe that I pass the first two of these requirements, as `tmp.txt` is generated and follows the example "ed" style diff that is provided in the help file. I have not set other shell-related parameters (shelltype, shellpipe, etc) in `$myvimrc`, but executing other commands with `:!` complete without issue.

There is no additional information in `:messages`, only the E97 error.

**Edit:**
If I remove `set shell=C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe` from `$myvimrc`, defaulting the shell back to `cmd.exe`, `diffthis` works as expected. It seems that [others have also had this problem when using Powershell](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8950/vim-diff-isnt-working-while-my-shell-is-powershell).

Below are captures of the command windows that pop up when running `diffthis` with both shells. The commands used are nearly identical.

[image: cmd]

[image: powershell]

I had speculated that the forward slashes apparent in the Powershell version of this attempt were problematic, but I am able to run this command exactly (with dummy files in place of the .tmp files) and it outputs what seems to be an adequate file for use with diff. I've also tried adding a `substitute` of forward slashes to back slashes to no avail.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have gvim installed on my Windows 10 machine, using the Windows installer for gvim, and the `:diffthis` command worked fine for me when I started gvim from the clickable icons. It also worked fine when I ran it from PowerShell. I didn't have to set any variables or anything. Do you have any custom configuration that might conflict with vim?

Comment: current vim comes with the diff functionality included, you don't need an external diff command anymore. Just make sure your `diffopt` setting includes `internal`

Comment: I have updated the original post with additional information. The problem is stemming from defining my `shell` as Powershell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem boils down to how vim/Powershell are A) encapsulating the command in quotes and B) handling white space in path names.

I am able to bypass this problem with the following changes to `$myvimrc`:

```
set shell=powershell
set shellcmdflag=-c
set shellquote="
set shellxquote=
```

Also a change in the default `MyDiff()` function within the `if` that sets the path to diff in the `cmd` variable:

```
  " below is the default
  " let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
  let cmd = "C:/diff"
```

This approach is dependent upon copying the `diff.exe` that ships with vim to a directory that doesn't contain spaces in the path for simplicity (C:\diff.exe).

The resulting command that is executed is:

```
powershell -c C:/diff -a --binary C:/<redacted>/a.tmp C:/<redacted>/b.tmp > C:/<redacted>/c.tmp
```